# Unable to send message to xmpp queue in activemq

Tags: java, jms, xmpp, activemq-classic

I am unable to send message to xmpp queue in `activemq`. I get the following example. As per the documentation I downloaded *wstx* jar and placed in `activemq/lib/optional` folder.

I get the following exception:

```
Caught: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [xmpp]
javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [xmpp]
        at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:35)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:252)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:265)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:238)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:184)
        at App$HelloWorldProducer.run(App.java:41)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [xmpp]
        at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:27)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.findTransportFactory(TransportFactory.java:196)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.connect(TransportFactory.java:66)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:250)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not find factory class for resource: META-INF/services/org/apache/activemq/transport/xmpp
        at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder$StandaloneObjectFactory.loadProperties(FactoryFinder.java:96)
        at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder$StandaloneObjectFactory.create(FactoryFinder.java:58)
        at org.apache.activemq.util.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:146)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.findTransportFactory(TransportFactory.java:193)
        ... 7 more
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please indicate what version of the broker you are using

Answer (score 1):

you need to add activemq-xmpp dependency to you maven pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
<artifactId>activemq-xmpp</artifactId>
<version>5.8.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

if you are not using maven , so add [activemq-xmpp.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-xmpp/5.8.0) to your /lib with all other jars